# Upload images to a subdomain folder like orkut in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

hai guys,
         I want to upload images through my web page to a folder in a subdomain of my website is it possible in asp.net.. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ASP.NET page performing the upload is not hosted on the same machine serving the subdomain you will need to install some script on each machine that you would call from the ASP.NET page, pass it the file bytes and it will save the file in the necessary subfolder. This script should be secure enough not to allow uploading to arbitrary directories.

Comment: how about uploading images to a static domain folder like orkut? I have a static domain with folder name images.... Can specify the folder link http://www.s1.mydomain.com/images where uploaded images can be stored....